# Compare depth data with previously stored depth data

Tags: c#, kinect, openni

What I need to do is store the depth data of a certain motion, then later compare if the player is doing that motion. So basically I need to compare the depth data of the current player with the recorded depth data and see how close the player resembles the recorded pose, taking a small error margin (like clothing) into account. I don't just need to know if they match yes or no, but also which part doesn't match.

I can't think of any way on how to do this by just comparing the data and every method I can think of to compare 2 depth maps would either be too slow for a real time application or not provide me with enough information. Does anyone have an idea how I could handle this?

The motion is of a person lying on the floor, so using the skeleton to compare positions and rotations of the joints isn't an option, the skeleton is all messed when lying on the floor. But I do still have the player shape.

I know the Kinect wasn't designed for tracking people on the floor but I know it can be done, there's at least 2 Xbox360 games that do it, The Biggest Loser Ultimate Workout and Your Shape Fitness Evolved 2012. For example:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NQC2mgCKsto#t=8m00s

I'm using the Kinect and the official Windows SDK 1.5 but even if the solution is OpenNi only, I'd still be able to use it.

Thanks in advance.